# Decode base64 in MongoDB fields

Tags: mongodb, base64

Some fields in the documents I have in MongoDB are encoded using base64. How can I decode all those fields automatically in all my documents?

Comment: ususally there's a reason why these fiels are encoded. What do you expect to see instead of the base64 encoded string?

Comment: I would like to statistically analyse what is encoded

Comment: Google for "javascript + decode + base64" - you should find many ready-to-use solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a create a custom MongoDB function.

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

And use $where operator in your find() queries, but you won't be able to use them in aggregation pipeline.